# Probability that two events will occur consecutively

Tags: probability, biology

Hi we are trying to determine the statistical significance of our summer water quality survey. 72 water samples were taken in two consecutive summer seasons. That is three sampling sites per week and three samples per site for eight weeks.

```
number of samples = 3*3*8
```

Each sample is cultured in a *petri dish* (chromogenic media that produces different colors per bacteria species) there are five colors that can be indentified.

A positive result is a 'dot' of one of the five colors. In one sample you can have all five colors or none. The number of dots depends on the quantity of bacteria present in the sample and the color determines the bacteria type.

If W is the family of colors and $w$ the quantity observed and X is a collection of three samples then:

$x_{i}$ = {$w_{a}, w_{b}, w_{c}, w_{d}, w_{e}$} is the possible outcome of one sample where ${w}$ is >= 0.

For each week the total number per color group per site is averaged, the average of each color group for one site for one week:

($\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^3 w_{ai}, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^3 w_{bi}, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^3 w_{ci} , \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^3 w_{di},\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^3 w_{ei}$)

What is the probability that one color group will have the greatest average value all three sites in the same week?

I was assuming it would look like this :

x = $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^3 w_{ai}$

Probability that x > than all other $x_{j}$ at one site = 1/5

Probability that this repeats at all three sites in the same week = (1/5)³ = .008

Probability that this happens twice = .00064

Therefore this is an unlikely outcome and statistically significant.

For full details check here:  http://mwshovel.pythonanywhere.com/dirt/microbiology.html

This is the chart of year over year results:

[Year over year results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZRjp.jpg)

Comment: I read this quickly and can’t promise much followup, but: Do you have reason to believe that the colors are equally likely to appear, that is, that if there were nothing going on, each color would show up with the same likelihood? That assumption seems to be part of your calculation. For example, if purple dots indicated water in the water sample, every sample would have lots of purple dots, and it would be very likely that one color group (purple) has the greatest average number of dots at every site every week, but this wouldn’t be significant.

Comment: yes the assumption is that all are equally likeley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all five colors are equally likely, and if the chance of a tie for "largest number" is negligible, and if the results at each site have independent probabilities, then in any given week there is indeed a $(1/5)^3$ chance that color A has the most dots in all three sites.

In the same week, there is also a $(1/5)^3$ chance that color B has the most dots.
And the same chances for colors C, D, and E.

In total, there is a $5 \times (1/5)^3 = 0.04$ chance that *some* single color will have the most dots at all three sites in a given week.

But there were many weeks of sampling, so the chance that this would happen at least once is much greater than $0.04.$

For example, looking just at the 2016 data, again assuming the probabilities are independent, the chance that there will be a single color with the most dots at all three sites in at least one of the eight weeks is
$$
1 - (0.96)^8 \approx 0.28.
$$
So the fact that this did happen once is not particularly significant.

On the other hand, if you look at both years, and ignore the "UV E. coli" data from 2017 (which were not recorded in 2016), you have three times when one color had the most dots at all three sites in one week. Under the same probability assumptions as before, this is the chance that a binomial variable with $n=16$ and $p = 0.04$ has a value greater than $2.$ That probability is approximately $0.024.$

Comment: Thanks, I ran a brute force script and repeated the experiment 1000 times. I defined a successful event as  a week where all sites had "Big Blue" as the max value, but only on week two or three(like the results). This occurred 0.002 - 0.004 times.  Don't explain this I will calculate this using probability instead of python and add it as a comment or answer.

Comment: It seems a reasonable hypothesis that there would be some correlation among the observations at three sites relatively close together on the same body of water. I would guess there is some kind of statistically significant indicator of that in the data. One pitfall of statistics, however, is when you start getting too specific about what kind of event happened that was unlikely to occur by chance, forming the hypothesis after seeing the data. I don't know if that's what you're doing here, but that's a question you should ask yourself.

Comment: David.  Actually the correlations are made in the section Economic and Environmental influences.  We made the hypothesis before we took the first sample(if you follow the link you can see the entire background in the Wiki). When the data correlated with what we hypothesized and with two of the three indicators we decided to seriously look at the possibility that this may be random.  Which of course it may be but not very likely. Thanks for your comment.